# Why is google pie chart showing up blank?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am trying to load a pie chart. I have other charts on the page (4 column and 2 Dual-Y Columns) and they are loading correctly, but the pie chart comes out blank. I get no error messages. Why is it showing up blank? What am I missing?

```
function insert_graph(graph_data_type, location, title, type, horizontal_axis, vertical_axis, height) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getdata.php?id=' + id+ '&graph=' + graph_data_type,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response === 'error') {
                //Error Handling
            } else if (null === response) {
                //Error Handling
            } else {
                chart_data = response;

                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                    drawGoogleGraph(response, location, title, type, horizontal_axis, vertical_axis,height);
                });

            }
        }
    });
}

function drawGoogleGraph(chart_data, chart_location, chart_title, chart_type, horizontal_axis, vertical_axis,height) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);

    switch (chart_type) {
        case 'column':
            var options = {
                    title: chart_title,
                    height: height,
                    hAxis: horizontal_axis,
                    vAxis: vertical_axis
                },
                chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#' + chart_location)[0]);

            break;
        case 'column_dual_y':
            var options = {
                    title: chart_title,
                    height: height,
                    hAxis: horizontal_axis,
                    vAxis: vertical_axis,
                    series: {
                        0: {axis: 'cytd'},
                        1: {axis: 'pytd'}
                    }
                },
                chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#' + chart_location)[0]);

            break;
        case 'pie_3d_exploding':
            var options = {
                    title: chart_title,
                    is3D: true,
                    height: height,
                    hAxis: horizontal_axis,
                    vAxis: vertical_axis
                },
                chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#' + chart_location)[0]);

            break;
    }

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And the data returned from a PHP Script

```
{"cols":[{"id":"product_type","label":"product_type","type":"string"},{"id":"cases","label":"cases","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"COFF"}{"v":"36046.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"COCO"},{"v":"710.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"TEA"},{"v":"635.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"NA"},{"v":"156.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"DAIR"},{"v":"155.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"BRWR"},{"v":"149.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"FRUI"},{"v":"70.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"ACC"},{"v":"2.00"}]}]}
```

Comment: Where is the javascript connecting the page to the php datasource. An ajax call for instance  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example#exampleusingphphtml-file

Comment: I edited it to show the full javascript (with some modifications)

Comment: @WhiteHat I get the title and background of teh chart, but NO actual pie chart

Comment: @WhiteHat I tried removing that but it was needed or else non of the charts show up. So I am fairly certain that is not my issue in this case

Comment: insert graph is called within the loop. I think you are confusing setOnLoadCallback with google.charts.load which can only be called once

Comment: not confused, `setOnLoadCallback` is called once `google.charts.load` finishes

Comment: Thank you for voting down my answer AFTER the question had been edited. That was a bit.... well rather not say... As far as I see no one else answered it nor would I after all